# Why does paper become uneven when soaked and dried?

Tags: everyday-life, water

Pouring water on a small part of sheet of paper and then drying it makes it *uneven*, it gets a *wave like appearance* and seems to have become larger in size.   Why?

Answer (score 4):

Paper is made of many, many tiny fibers. When you wet a piece of paper, those fibers absorb water and swell up. As they dry, the relaxed fibers don't go back to exactly where they started. Some will have shifted or "untangled", moving out of the plane of the original paper. So yes, the paper actually does become slightly bigger because the fibers have stretched.

Comment: i learnt that paper consist of CHO- bonds and when water is poured on it due to its high dielectric constant it weakens CHO- bonds. when dried bonds are formed but are not orderly. they cant regain their shape due to presence of starch. how far is this true?